# What means free?

Tags: cognito-forms

What does Free mean when you have payment of 1%?

Answer (score 1):

1% refers to the percentage that Cognito Forms receives from each successful transaction on your form. If you're not using Cognito Forms to collect payment, this 1% does not apply.